# Trigger a pipeline dependes on Open a PR and the later push to the open PR

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

What is needed?

The pipeline is deploy the resources to the development environment for testing. The pipeline shall be triggered when a PR is opened that a feature branch want to merge to the development branch. Trigger the pipeline by open the PR is easy. However, things are not always going well for the first try. things may need to be changed after code review and a new commit is needed.

Issue:

But how to trigger the pipeline when the new commit is pushed to the un-merged feature branch? would the **edited type** below do the trick?

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, edited]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `synchronize` type, as example:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, edited, synchronize]
```

See also https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request